# Can't open file in Julia

Tags: file-io, julia

This might be an incredibly basic question but I can't find the answer online. I can't open any files in Julia when they aren't in the same directory as my script. So if I want to do `readall(open("~/Documents/dictionary.txt"))` I always get a file does not exist error. This is an application where the script takes file paths (which may be absolute or relative) from the command line. Python handles this pretty easily but Julia seems to be having trouble for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried opening files without `~`, home directory reference? It should work OK. To use `~`, try `open(expanduser(path))`.

Comment: Right, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1136 (tilde expansion is not currently supported)

Answer (score 3):

On unix based systems the function `expanduser("~")` returns the current user's home directory, so appending this at the beginning this will work,

```
julia> open(expanduser("~")*"/Documents/dictionary.txt")
```

Credits to @Dan Getz.